# I not able to receive a call when app is close in Twilio VoIP in flutter

Tags: flutter, voip

I not able to receive a call when app is close i tried all things but not working, getting call notification but I can't receiving a call.

Comment: You have to implement native code in your flutter app for making it compatible to background calls or you can give connectycube a try it may do the job for you but last time when I worked with background calling in flutter VoIP webrtc based I ended up using callkit and callkeep natively java & swift. Here's the link to connectycube https://pub.dev/packages/connectycube_flutter_call_kit